# difference between basic struts and modular struts

Tags: maven, struts2, maven-archetype, appfuse

While creating a Struts application with Maven I found two archetypes: `appfuse-basic-struts` and `appfuse-modular-struts`.

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [QuickStart Guide](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart)

> AppFuse comes in a number of different flavors. To optimize and simplify your experience as a user, we've created a number of different archetypes (a.k.a. starter projects). There are currently three types of AppFuse Archetypes: light, basic and modular. Light archetypes are bare-bones, basic archetypes contain User Management and Security and modular archetypes contain "core" and "web" modules and are ideal for creating projects that have a re-usable backend.